# Задание написать программу которая проверяла бы введенное число на четность/нечетность, в списке ошибок сообщение идентификвтор If не определен,

Tags: c++

```
#include using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int a;
    cout << "Введите число" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    If(a / 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Это число четное" << endl;
    }
    else { cout << "Это число нечетное" << endl; }
}
```

Comment: `if` а не `If`. А на четность нужно проверять с помощью `%` (остаток от деления)

Comment: Используйте кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1165123/edit), чтобы привести вопрос в нормальный вид: отформатировать код и ошибки, сделать индексируемый заголовок и описать проблему

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int a;

    cout << "Введите число" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    //if (a / 2 == 0) {      проверка на чётность делается остатком от деления, а не делением
    if (a % 2 == 0){
        cout << "Это число четное" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Это число нечетное" << endl;
    }

}
```